# Understanding Basis for a Topology

Tags: general-topology

- Definition. If $X$ is a set, a **basis** for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X $
  called basis elements euch that

(1) For each $x \in X,$ there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.

(2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$, then there is a basis element $B_{3}$ containing $x$ such that $B_{3} \subset B_{1} \cap B_{2}$.

Example. Let $X=\left\{a,b,c,d,e\right\},$ $\tau=\left\{\emptyset,\left\{a,b\right\},\left\{c,d\right\},\left\{a,b,c,d\right\},X\right\}$, $\mathcal{B}=\left\{\left\{a,b\right\},\left\{c,d\right\},\emptyset,X\right\}.$ Is $\mathcal{B}$ a bais for $\tau$?

My attempt. Checking $i)$ Basis elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are $\left\{a,b\right\},\left\{c,d\right\},\emptyset,X.$ We can see that  For each $x \in X,$ there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$, that for $a\in X$, there exist the basis $\left\{a,b\right\}$ containing $a$, etc.

Checking $ii)$ $a\in\left\{a,b\right\}\cap X$ and ... How can I show that $ii)$? May you check checking $i)$?

Comment: Suppose $a$ belongs to the intersection of two elements in the basis. Then you do not have many options: either $B_1=B_2=\{a,b\}$ (then $B_3=B_1=B_2$) or $B_1=\{a,b\}$ and $B_2=X$ (in this case $B_3=B_1$) or both $B_1,B_2=X$ and then $B_3=B_1=B_2$. The symmetric cases are analogous. The same reasoning applies to either one of the elements. Observe that for $e$, the only possibility is $e\in\emptyset$ and it is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a$, for instance. It belongs to $3$ elements of $\mathcal B$: $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,b,c,d\}$, and $X$. But $\{a,b\}$ is a subset of each of them. So, if $$B_1,B_2\in\bigl\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\},X\bigr\},$$you take $B_3=\{a,b\}$ and then $a\in B_3$ and $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Now, do the same thing with the remaining elements of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $e$ is also an element of $X$, but it not contained in any basis element.

Comment: then, we say $\mathcal{B}$ is not a basis for $\tau$,right?

Comment: May you say more clearly?

Comment: Right, it is not a basis, since it does not fulfill requirement no. 1

Comment: Thanks for answer and comment